# Unable to read encrypted email address

Tags: encryption, robotframework

I am trying to pass encrypted email address in my robot framework but i keep getting the below error. How do i fix this?

ValueError: Send Message failed: {"'crypt:\Cryptedvalue'": (553, b"5.1.3 The recipient address <'address'\n5.1.3 'some value'='> is not a valid\n5.1.3 RFC-5321 address. Learn more at\n5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 g9-20020a05620a108900b0067b13036bd5sm5495282qkk.52 - gsmtp")}

Answer (score 0):

Programming is like Excel. Start backwards.

Were you able to insert the email address without the encryption first?

Then use an easier encryption or try to create the insertion using code conversion without encrypting the code conversion like using a binary file.

Then use the base encryption, a popular encryption (md5), and then move on to your desired encryption SHA -.

Comment: Yes I was able to use the email address without the encryption and it works fine.

Comment: by email address, are you referring to an email server, are you referring to an email field in a form? ... according to others with the same question is that there is a space at the end of the email address in the form or in the code itself.

Comment: I am new to all this process but here is what did , using  python -m CryptoLibrary i followed the steps, created a public key, encrypted the email address(example@gmail.com) and password and got a result that looks like this - crypt:8HmWMmpmTsD7jJ67A4hsgb Vy5DNpkJuuxTqc1B88237XjUmcnm5C0NaezWVW9UmEXxc2la74rgO1fHg6/+bgV+jzAg=
so when i place the  above crypt instead of putting the email address (example@gmail.com), in my robot framework code that sends email when the test fails, and thats when it throws the above error.

Comment: did you try adding an additional equal sign to the end of the encryption. Base64 is two equal signs

Comment: I found the error. It was because I generated the public key multiple times. Its working now. Thank You